# rc.local not being executed when os boots up

Tags: shell-script, centos

I have a script that needs to be run when os boots up. I added it to `/etc/rc.local`. It was working fine for sometime but now `rc.local` does not load at boot time.

When i checked the permissions on the file,

```
[root@localhost etc]# ls -al rc.local 
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 288 Mar 14 12:40 rc.local
```

So I used `chmod a+x rc.local` to set executable permission. But on reboot it didn't start. Again, `ls -al rc.local` showed that `rc.local` doesn't have executable permission.

Why did it get reset? How to make `rc.local` executable permanantly?

Update : 
Ok, so I did `chmod u+x rc.local` and now when the os boots up, the file is displayed as having executable permission. But still it isn't getting executed.

Ouput of `ls -lZ`

```
[root@localhost etc]# ls -lZ rc.local 
-rwxrw-rw-. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   rc.local
```

Comment: There is a `.` after the permissions in the `ls` output which indicates that the file has an selinux context.  Can you add the output of `ls -lZ rc.local` to your question?

Comment: @Flup : Thanks for answering. Updated the question.

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: It's a symlink, `/etc/rc.local -> rc.d/rc.local`. Have you created the target manually in `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: Am using CentOS 6.3. I didn't manually create `/etc/rc.local`. Should I delete it and recreate?

Comment: I made a backup of `/etc/rc.local`, copied `rc.d/rc.local` using `--preserve=context`. So `ls -Z /etc/rc.local` gives `-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0 rc.local`. Still it isn't working.

Comment: You didnt need to change /etc/rc.d/rc.local right access.You edit rc.local and enter some commands inside rc.local with full path.The system will read rc.local and run a command inside rc.local.My default rc.local right access :-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  473 Nov 20  2015 rc.local

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 7 at least, `rc.local` is not executable by default and won't be executed. You'll have to `chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local`